# Is it safe to use FreeType inside a proprietary closed-source software?

Tags: gpl, multi-licensing

Many of libraries, that have LGPL or permissive licenses, depends on FreeType, that have multi-licensing (FTL/*GPL*). My question is: if FreeType can be used under any of these licenses, can someone juridically oblige to open the source code of the proprietary product, that distributed in binary form, using the "permissive" dependency, that uses FreeType?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it safe to use FreeType inside a proprietary closed-source software?

Yes.

> if FreeType can be used under any of these licenses, can someone juridically oblige to open the source code of the proprietary product, that distributed in binary form, using the "permissive" dependency, that uses FreeType?

The short answer is no. The thing about the FreeType license is that you are required to make an explicit choice among the licensing options. Document the choice you made and you should be good.

Additional details based on @Raphael10 comments:

> you can choose between FTL compatible with GPL version 3, and GPL version 2. In both cases, as far as I understand, FreeType is not that compatible with closed source (propetary) sw. Is it correct?

FreeType license at https://www.freetype.org/license.html states that there are these choices:

> FreeType comes with two licenses from which you can choose the one
> which fits your needs best.
>
> - The FreeType License (FTL) is the most commonly used one. It is a BSD-style license with a credit clause and thus compatible with the
>   GNU Public License (GPL) version 3, but not with the GPL version 2.
> - The GNU General Public License (GPL), version 2. Use it for all projects which use the GPLv2 also, or which need a license compatible
>   to the GPLv2.

The choice we are discussing here is the [FreeType License](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/freetype/freetype/-/blob/master/docs/FTL.TXT) option which is a [permissive](https://scancode-licensedb.aboutcode.org/freetype.html) license and can be used alright when combined with proprietary code. We are NOT talking about the GPL option.

Comment: I suppose, you're right, but I will, as far as possible, switch my projects to stb_truetype.h just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Philippe Ombredanne from the FreeType licenses: https://www.freetype.org/license.html you can choose between FTL compatible with GPL version 3, and GPL version 2. In both cases, as far as I understand, FreeType is not that compatible with closed source (propetary) sw.  https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-general-public-license-v3-(gpl-3).      https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-general-public-license-v2        Is it correct?

Comment: @Raphael10 see my updated answer. The FTL license is what we are discussing here, not the GPL alternative.